# How to change font color of random individual text in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I know,  font can be formatted in different ways in wxPython using Rich Text. Like

```
richtext = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1,"Dummy Text Here",size=(100, 100),style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_RICH2)
richtext .SetInsertionPoint(0)
richtext .SetStyle(2, 5, wx.TextAttr("red", "blue"))
```

But, I will have no prior knowledge of the position of the text whose font color I want to change.

Is there anyways to change the font color using condition, rather than the position of the text in wxPython.

Answer (score 0):

Use the find method on the string to get the position of the text you want to change.